# Go.CD like interface for azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Will have a lot of pipelines in azure and I was thinking if there is some interface like the one used by go.cd.

Here it is :

[image]

So in this interface we represent pipelines as boxs that we can arranged by group what I find very clear

Is there any solution like that in azure pipelines world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any solution like that in azure pipelines world ?

If you want the interface which same like the **box** in GoCD, I'm afraid that no, not have the same one in Azure Devops. In Azure Devops, all pipelines displayed as **bar**.

Also, for pipelines arranged, we only offered the method : arrange by **folder**. Shown like this:

[image]

In the pipeline of Azure Devops, it display in a layer-by-layer progressive form of the folder. For a specific pipeline record, it displayed as a bar instead of a box.

When you start browsing one specific pipeline, it can list all recently records of this pipeline, including trigger method, branch and commit message.

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? ADO has a number of options that are not so different from the image in the question.